# Html5 video not playing on bxslider

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video, bxslider

Currently i have a bxSlider, which has a video on the second slide. I've got the video working inside of the slider fine with the video tag. But what I'm trying to do is get the video to play once the slide is active and current.

This is my current on slide after.

```
onSlideAfter: function(currentSlide, totalSlides, currentSlideHtmlObject){

                $j(currentSlide).addClass('active-slide');

                if(currentSlideHtmlObject == 1){
                    var video = document.getElementById("video");
                    console.log(video.play());
                } else if(currentSlideHtmlObject == 2 || currentSlideHtmlObject == 0) {
                    $j('video')[0].currentTime = 0;
                }

                modifyDelay(currentSlideHtmlObject);
            }
```

Ignore my console log, I was just seeing if the .play did anything. It doesn't. Yet the video doesn't seem to play once the slide shows. If i set the video to auto play it will work, but this just doesn't seem to work.

If I run:

```
document.getElementById("video").play();
```

I get the following: (which i don't fully understand).

```
Promise {[[PromiseStatus]]: "pending", [[PromiseValue]]: undefined}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply use the callback [`onSlideBefore()`](http://bxslider.com/options#onSlideBefore). More details in the source in the comments.

#### SNIPPET

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Multi BxSlider</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bxslider/4.2.14/jquery.bxslider.min.css" />
  <style>
    /* This centers the img and video */
    
    img,
    video {
      display: block;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <ul class="bx">
    <li data-idx="0">
      <img src="http://dummyimage.com/640x360/000/fff.png&text=1">
    </li>
    <li data-idx="1">

      <!-- Set each video id so that it corresponds with the `data-idx`
      So if slide <li> is data-idx="1", then video id="vid1"-->

      <video id="vid1" class="vid" src="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4" controls></video>
    </li>
    <li data-idx="2">
      <img src="http://dummyimage.com/640x360/000/fc0.png&text=3">
    </li>
    <li data-idx="3">
      <img src="http://dummyimage.com/640x360/000/0ff.png&text=4">
    </li>
    <li data-idx="4">
      <img src="http://dummyimage.com/640x360/000/b52.png&text=5">
    </li>

  </ul>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bxslider/4.2.14/jquery.bxslider.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    var bx = $(".bx").bxSlider({
      pager: false,
      nextText: '',
      prevText: '',
      infiniteLoop: false,
      /*
      This callback will fire a function 
      before a slide completes it's
      course to it's destination
      */
      onSlideBefore: autoPlay
    });
    /*
    This function just uses the `to` parameter
    I put all of them there because bxSlider expects 
    them there, I have bad luck if I don't... don't ask:P
    */
    function autoPlay($ele, from, to) {
      /* 
      idx is the slide index number
      if there is a video within 
      the slide then play it.
      */
      var idx = parseInt(to, 10);
      var vid = document.querySelector('#vid' + idx);

      if (vid) {
        vid.play();
      }
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, that solved my issue. OnSlideBefore, doing it on slideafter was the wrong way around >_< thanks again.

Comment: You're welcome, sir. Yes, I learned that valuable lesson as well and after 3 years of heavy use and constant modifications, I have yet to utilize `onSlideAfter` successfully.

Comment: Did anyone run into an issue with this not working in Chrome. Plays everywhere else.

Comment: @RyanSwanson Updated the bxSlider files from v.4.2.5 to v.4.2.14, Thanks for the heads up. Let me know if you still experience any issues.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to get the 1st slide in the show to play you can do that using onSliderLoad() - and using a wrapper method to get both to work.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
    video: true,
    onSliderLoad: autoPlay,
    onSlideBefore: autoPlayWrapper
  });
});

// Calls the autoPlay function with the index of the next slide
function autoPlayWrapper(asdf,asdf,index){
  autoPlay(index);
}

// play the video in the slide at index
function autoPlay(index){
  var idx = parseInt(index,10);
  var vid = document.querySelector("#vid"+idx);
  if(vid){
    vid.play();
  }
}
</script>
```